# I am not able to execute many APIs of JWinAuto.Has anyone able to implement all APIs?

Tags: java, autoit

I installed and configured it but only two functions are working :AU3_WinMinimizeAll and AU3_WinMaximizeAll

Comment: JWinAuto is pretty old (2007), maybe it's just not compatible with actual versions of AutoIt anymore. Have you tried the junit tests?

Comment: BTW - JWinAuto does not implement anything, it's just the library interface.

Comment: I am not looking to test windows application using Junit..I wanna automate the windows functions using JWinAUto  Can you suggest any other java based open source tool to simulate windows functionality behaviour??

Comment: C'mon - I talked about the junit test that are shipped with JWinAuto. To see if the are successful or if they fail. The lib should allow calling more then just those two methods....

Comment: JNA is pretty useful for calling windows API functions without the clutter and confusion of JNI (which is used under the hood of course). I have also had pretty good success at calling AutoIt from Java and visa versa and having the communicate with each other via sockets (usually standard in and out).

Answer (score 0):

Try this discussion [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/105904-autoitx-33-and-jwinauto-java-jna/). Basically AutoIt has sinced moved to unicode, so the calls from the JNA interface need to pass `com.sun.jna.WString`s everywhere they previously passed `String`s.

eg.

was

`public int AU3_WinWait(String szTitle, String szText, int nTimeout);`

now

`public int AU3_WinWait(WString szTitle, WString szText, int nTimeout);`